# google dfp pubads().refresh() not working as expected

Tags: google-dfp

I'm using some of the new features in Google DFP and can't get a single add to refresh on it's own.  I can refresh all ads on the page but I can't get just one to refresh by itself.

I've been trying the following code to get one add to refresh without luck:

```
   var slot1 = googletag.display('/6900315/myad2', [300, 250], 'div-2');
        googletag.pubads().refresh([slot1]);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Full source:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var googletag = googletag || {};
googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
(function () {
    var gads = document.createElement('script');
    gads.async = true;
    gads.type = 'text/javascript';
    var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
    gads.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
 '//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
    var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
})();
</script>


script type='text/javascript'>
googletag.cmd.push(function () {
    googletag.pubads().enableAsyncRendering();
    googletag.defineSlot("/69003153/myad1", [728, 90], "div-1").addService         (googletag.pubads());
    googletag.defineSlot("/69003153/myad2", [300, 250], "div-2").addService    (googletag.pubads());
    googletag.enableServices();
});
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function changeAd() {
    googletag.cmd.push(function () {
        var slot1 = googletag.display('/6900315/myad2', [300, 250], 'div-2');
        googletag.pubads().refresh([slot1]);
        //googletag.pubads().refresh();


    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">


    <div id='div-1' style='width:728px; height:90px;'>
<script type='text/javascript'>
     googletag.cmd.push(function () { googletag.display('div-1'); });
</script>
</div>


 <!-- BoxAdd_Details -->
<div id='div-2' style='width:300px; height:250px;'>
   <script type='text/javascript'>
        googletag.cmd.push(function () { googletag.display('div-2); });
</script>
</div>

<input type="button" name="test" title="test" onclick="javascript:window.changeAd();"     value="Reload Ad" />
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm also having the same problem. I haven't got my ads to refresh yet, but I should suggest that you don't need to redeclare your ad slot in changeAd().

Instead of:

```
googletag.cmd.push(function () {
    googletag.pubads().enableAsyncRendering();
    googletag.defineSlot("/69003153/myad1", [728, 90], "div-1").addService         (googletag.pubads());
    googletag.defineSlot("/69003153/myad2", [300, 250], "div-2").addService    (googletag.pubads());
    googletag.enableServices();
});
```

Try:

```
googletag.cmd.push(function () {
    googletag.pubads().enableAsyncRendering();
    slot1 = googletag.defineSlot("/69003153/myad1", [728, 90], "div-1").addService         (googletag.pubads());
    slot2 = googletag.defineSlot("/69003153/myad2", [300, 250], "div-2").addService    (googletag.pubads());
    googletag.enableServices();
});
```

Declaring them without 'var' preceding them makes the slots global in scope. In your `changeAd()` function, simply call

```
googletag.pubads().refresh([slot1]);
```

I'm not even sure if you need to place that inside `googletag.cmd.push()`

When I execute it this way, my ads still dont refresh, but running console.log(slot1) shows that the ad slot is alive and kicking...

Can anyone else help further?

Comment: thanks that worked a treat! One add is refreshing now using the code above using global scope for slot1

Comment: It works. Make sure you include googletag.pubads().enableAsyncRendering(); above defineSlot() as I didnt and took me a while to release why code was not working

Comment: googletag.pubads().refresh(); works fine without argument inside :)

Comment: I've never been able to get pubads().refresh() to do anything, Did you end up getting this to work?

Comment: This is now working via the jquery.dfp project https://github.com/coop182/jquery.dfp.js and the issue https://github.com/coop182/jquery.dfp.js/issues/8

Comment: googletag.pubads().enableAsyncRendering(); this line of code, saved my life !! God bless you man !!! Thank you so much :D