# Multiple Ad/Creative Sizes in DFP

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-dfp

I'm wondering how one would go about creating different ad / creative sizes for different browser widths / screen resolutions in DFP.  I found this DFP article regarding this issue, but it was specifically for mobile users, and they do not give any code, rather just a method.  Here is the article:

http://support.google.com/dfp_premium/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2615435

In it they give a code method that looks like this:

```
if screen size < 300px
ad tag size = 216
else if screen size < 600px
ad tag size = 300
else
ad tag size = 600
```

But this article was for mobile ads only. :(  Here is a jsfiddle of my ad image: http://jsfiddle.net/EptwH/3/

If anyone could inform me on whether or not there is a method to have multiple creative/ad sizes for different browser widths, that would be amazing.  And one more thing to add, I do not COMPLETELY want to change the ad dimensions, the ratio will stay the same... so for example, I'd like a 100x50 ad, then a 200x100, then a 300x150, then a 400x200 etc.  If anyone could help me out, or let me know if this is even possible....that would be amazing!

Comment: I assume you are referring to your own house ads? Since standard ad slots are not scalable.

Comment: See my example here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40243168/dfp-responsive-ads/40247759#40247759

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you see the JS code that DFP asks you to embed into your page, they are split into three "phases" :

- first you define the available slots on the page
- second you enable the service
- third you ask the slots to be filled.

In the very first step, you can have some conditional code. So you could replace this statement :

```
googletag.defineSlot('/1234567/my_slot', [728, 90], 'gpt-apps-large').addService(googletag.pubads());
```

with a conditional :

```
if(window.width>728) {
   googletag.defineSlot('/1234567/my_slot', [728, 90], 'gpt-apps-large').addService(googletag.pubads());
} else {
   googletag.defineSlot('/1234567/my_slot', [468, 60], 'gpt-apps-large').addService(googletag.pubads());
}
```

**Edit:** Bonus tip -- use the information here https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=181070 to debug your ad delivery.

Comment: hey man, there's no doubt in my mind that this will work, but i tried it out on my jsfiddle and it just gives me a blank add, no matter what the browser width is: http://jsfiddle.net/EptwH/4/ Would I have to actually upload the creative as one ofmy specified sizes in the javascript code?  It seems really simple, but it's just not working at the moment... if you could get the jsfiddle (posted in the original questions) working, that would be amazing!!

Comment: you need to define each ad slot ( 728x90, 468x60 in my examples ) and have creatives for each size, yes.

Comment: hey hexblot, i appreciate your input and answer, but when I tried your  code the ad does not change sizes at all. I specfied 3 ad sizes for a line item as well as the ad unit and I uploaded 3 creatives all for the specified sizes. When I use the generated dfp ad tags, the ads change sizes on refresh, but again... I would like the ads to change sizes based on browser width, just like you specified in your answer.  So when I try to do this, the ad does not change size on browser width change. Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qqXEj/5/ do you want me to create a separate question for this?

Comment: the above code is meant to serve ads based on browser width at the time of the page load, not resize them dynamically as the browser resizes, if that is what you mean. To "refresh" ads after the page has loaded you should be using the `.refresh()` method. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298247/google-dfp-pubads-refresh-not-working-as-expected) for some insight (not exactly what you want, but close enough).

Comment: hey hexblot, thanks for the help so far here is my final question regarding this whole DFP browser width issue.. if you could help me out, it would mean so so so so so........ so much to me! Here is the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423189/changing-ad-size-based-on-browser-width-in-dfp Again, thanks for the help thus far. :)

Comment: don't mean to be pushy but did you get a chance to look at the question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423189/changing-ad-size-based-on-browser-width-in-dfp would mean the wooorld to me if you could help me out! :)

Answer (score 0):

For me simple `window.width` no working, but this good:

```
if(window.innerWidth>728) {
   googletag.defineSlot('/1234567/my_slot', [728, 90], 'gpt-apps-large').addService(googletag.pubads());
} else {
   googletag.defineSlot('/1234567/my_slot', [468, 60], 'gpt-apps-large').addService(googletag.pubads());
}
```